# Table View Scroll issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

There is a reply button at table view section header. On a click of that button table view section footer appears.i want, when I click reply button my table view scroll down to section footer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code at when you need tableview scroll to bottom

```
NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: cells_count-1 inSection: sections_count-1];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated: YES];
```